# Is there a better way to ask this question so that it doesn't violate the Programmers StackExchange rules?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

There are many abstract concepts programmers encounter and remember before needing a reference manual or Google, and few other disciplines require this same level of abstract thought.

I can't help be feel that there must be something different to the way programmers remember concepts since these concepts aren't as easily tied to the real world.

Is there a better way to ask this question in that context and so that it doesn't violate the Programmers StackExchange rules?:

[Are there any memorization techniques that exist for programmers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/168729/are-there-any-memorization-techniques-that-exist-for-programmers)

And if so, what action should I take. Do I simply post a new question?

Comment: Don't post a new question. If this discussion concludes that there are ways to improve your question, you can simply edit it, and people can vote to re-open it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question as it's phrased isn't good for any Stack Exchange site. You're asking for a list of techniques about learning or memorizing concepts, and there's [an entire blog post on why such questions aren't good for the Stack Exchange format](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). You'd have to reformulate your question to make it viable anywhere.

However, since memorization and learning aren't exclusive to software developers, I can't see how any question would be on-topic here on Programmers. Perhaps you could check out some other sites:

- The [Personal Productivity Stack Exchange](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) has questions about [learning](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) and [memory](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory), so some of the questions might be useful to you.
- The [CogSci Stack Exchange](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) has tags about [problem solving](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-solving), [learning](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), and [memory](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) (including specialized [short-term](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/long-term-memory) and [long-term](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/long-term-memory)). However, they have more rigorous standards for their questions - take a look at some of their top questions and the FAQ to understand the kind of questions they accept.